# S3 Bucket CORS configuration not accepted

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, cors

People of the internet, I need your help. I'm trying to put this code in my S3 butcket CORS and I get this error: `Expected params.CORSConfiguration.CORSRules to be an Array`

```
[
    {
        "AllowedHeaders": [
            "*"
        ],
        "AllowedMethods": [
            "GET",
            "PUT",
            "POST",
        ],
        "AllowedOrigins": [
            "*"
        ],
        "ExposeHeaders": [],
        "MaxAgeSeconds": 3000
    }
]
```

[image: Look here]

Comment: https://s3-presigned-url.workshop.aws/preparation/cors_config.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your JSON is not valid. If you test this with an online (or other) validator, you'll see an error in your AllowedMethods, specifically that the final value in that array has a trailing comma (valid JavaScript, but invalid JSON).

Change the policy to this:

```
[{
    "AllowedHeaders": [
        "*"
    ],
    "AllowedMethods": [
        "GET",
        "PUT",
        "POST"
    ],
    "AllowedOrigins": [
        "*"
    ],
    "ExposeHeaders": [],
    "MaxAgeSeconds": 3000
}]
```

Comment: thank you! my bad, I guess I just need to learn read the error messages. The message is clear, they were already telling me its an Invalid JSON